# How to disable Postfix SPF from rejecting mail?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I am having an issue with Postfix and SPF that I can't seem to figure out. I have installed SPF for Postfix using the guide on this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/SPF) (postfix-policyd-spf-perl).

However, I don't want Postfix or Mail::SPF to "reject" mail if it fails. All I want it to do is add the Authentication result to the emails header like it normally does. I have tried to find a config file for postfix-policyd-spf-perl but I can't seem to locate anything.

Below is an example of the rejection message:

```
mail.xxxxxx.com #<mail.xxxxxxxxx.com #5.7.1 smtp; 550 5.7.1
<xxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.com>: Recipient address rejected: Please see 
http://www.openspf.net/Why?s=mfrom;id=xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com;ip=xxx.xx.xx.xxx;r=MAILER>
```

Comment: Post your main.cf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so postfix-policyd-spf-perl doesn't have a configuration file. I had to switch to the python version in order to configure the SPF settings.